# Batch script to extract same line from each log file

Tags: batch-file

I have a number of text files that are always the same number of lines - 42 and always the same type of information on each line.  Also each line starts with a header.

What I would like is a batch script to keep line 30 of the text file remove the others and save the file.

I have tried to look find the line based on the information between two line.  In this case the heading on line 30 (Job Notes) and the heading on line 31 (Job Number) and then write the information to a new file.

Line 30 begins with

```
Job Notes= (information specifically about the job)
```

Line 31 begins with

```
Job Number=
```

This is the code I used (which i found elsewhere on this site) and i am getting no output at all.  Have tried other ways as well so don't really have to use this method if you can see a better one, basically i just want line 30 to be the only information in the file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
SET "sourcedir=C\Batch"
SET "destdir=C:\Batch\Extract"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "Job Notes"^<"%sourcedir%\7099.txt" ') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "Job Number"^<"%sourcedir%\7099.txt" ') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%sourcedir%\00007099.txt" ') do (
IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%destdir%\newfile.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
David

Comment: You're missing a : in the SET "Sourcedir" line. That could have an impact ;)

Comment: Thanks .. it was getting late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1, using findstr string numeration

```
for %%a in (*.log) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%b in (
        'findstr /n "^" "%%a" ^| findstr /b "30:"'
    ) do (
        echo(%%c>"%%a"
    )
)
```

Option 2, using for command skip lines

```
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.log) do (
    set "line="
    for /f "usebackq skip=29 delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do if not defined line set "line=%%b"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo(!line!>"%%a"
    endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want you the `/N` flag with `FINDSTR`:

```
FINDSTR /N /R ".*" *.txt | FINDSTR /R "\<30:" > out.txt
```

Explanation:

```
FINDSTR /N /R ".*" *.txt
```

finds every line (`".*"` with the regex flag `/R`) in every text file (`*.txt`) and appends its line number to the front (`/N`).  This is then piped to

```
FINDSTR /R "\<30:"
```

which only grabs lines starting with (that's the `\<` bit) `30:`.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
SET "sourcedir=C\Batch"
SET "destdir=C:\Batch\Extract"
for /f "skip=29tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('type "%sourcedir%\7099.txt" ') do ECHO(%%b >"%destdir%\newfile.txt"&goto nextstep
:nextstep
GOTO :EOF
```

should do the job, finding line 30 (by skipping 29) then tokenising on the separating `=` and having output exactly one, going to the next step in your batch.

Having said that, however - you do realise that you are setting `start` and `end` using `7099.txt` and then picking the data from `00007099.txt` don't you? Does `00007099.txt` exist?

And `c:\batch` seems a mighty strange place to store data files to me. Personally, I'd put batch files there (and include `c:\batch` into your `PATH`) but it's your system...