# Batch file to list txt and mp3 files - using the list extract the same lines from the text files

Tags: batch-file

I've had some help from a previous question on this already. [Batch script to extract same line from each log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701784/batch-script-to-extract-same-line-from-each-log-file)
But this question is the next level up. What I am trying to do is to create a list of all text files and mp3 files in a folder.  The files are pairs and have matching names 1.txt, 1.mp3, 2.txt, 2.mp3. Count the list for the number of files.  Extract the same lines from the text files and save the files again.  Modify one of the lines of text and save again.  Move the text file and mp3 file.
I can create the list.
I can count the list and store the count.
I can move the files.
I can modify the *.txt text files to only have one line (eg line 30) but I can't keep multiple lines, I also can't read from my list to do this to all of the text files in the list.
I can't modify the line.
I would like Line 15, 17 and 30.
Line 15 is File Type=X (where X is a number)
Line 17 is Location=Y (where Y is a number)
Line 30 is Job Notes=word word XXXXXX date time YYYYYY (where XXXXXX is a six-digit number and the date is dd/MM/yyyy and the time h:mm AM and YYYYYY is a six-digit number)
Line 30 is the Line is would like modified as below

```
Name=word word  
File number=XXXXXX  
Date=dd/MM/yyyy
```

So the final text file would look like this

```
File Type=X (from line 15)
Location=Y (from line 17)
Name=word word (from line 30)
File number=XXXXXX  (from line 30)
Date=dd/MM/yyyy  (from line 30)
```

This is my code

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set src_folder=C:\Users\Acer_AT3400\Desktop\New_Project
set mov_folder=C:\Users\Acer_AT3400\Desktop\New_Project\Move
set file_list=C:\Users\Acer_AT3400\Desktop\New_Project\Extractor\FileList.txt
set cnt=0
set cntLogFile=%date:~4%
set cntLogFile=%cntLogFile:~-4%-%cntLogFile:~,2%-%cntLogFile:~3,2%
set mveLogFile=%date:~4%
set mveLogFile=%mveLogFile:~-4%-%mveLogFile:~,2%-%mveLogFile:~3,2%
call :run >FileList.txt
call :cntIt
call :ExtractIt
call :mveIt
exit /b

:run

for %%F in (%src_folder%\*.*) do echo %%~nxF

)
exit /b

:cntIt

for /f "delims=" %%f in (%file_list%) do set /a cnt+=1
echo %date%,%cnt%,%time%>>C:\Users\Acer_AT3400\Desktop\New_Project\Extractor\Transfer_Log\count_%cntLogFile%.txt
)
exit /b

:ExtractIt

for /f "delims=" %%f in (%file_list%) in %%a do (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%b in (
        'findstr /n "^" "%%a" ^| findstr /b "30:"'
    ) do (
        echo(%%c>"%%a"
    )
)
exit /b

:mveIt

if not exist "%mov_folder%" mkdir "%mov_folder%"

for /f "delims=" %%f in (%file_list%) do (
    move "%src_folder%\%%f" "%mov_folder%\"
if %errorlevel% GTR 0 (echo MOVE FAILURE,%src_folder%,%%f,%time%,>>%mov_folder%\move_%mveLogFile%.txt) else (echo MOVE SUCCESSFUL,%src_folder%,%%f,%time%,>>%mov_folder%\move_%mveLogFile%.txt)
)

exit /b
```

I would be very grateful for any advice.
David - worried he has bitten of more than he can chew.

New information as requested.
I have entered Text for where text is used (and Text Text for two words etc) and Number for a number.
Text file Before.

```
[CMP DESC]
Text=Number
Text=Text
Text Text=Number
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text=Number
Text Text=Number
Text Text=Text Text
Text Text=d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss AM
Text Text Text=Number
Text Text=d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss AM
Text Text Text=Number
Text Text Text=Number
File Type=4
Text Text Text=Text
Location=3
Text Text=Number
Text=Number
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Job Notes=John Smith 123456 dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss PM 654321
Text Text=Text
Text=Number.mp3
Text=Number
Text=Number
Text=
Text Text=Number
Text Text=
Text Text=Text
Text Text=Text
Text Text=Text
Text=
Text=
```

You will have to include a line like this so it has actual numbers to deal with.

```
Job Notes=John Smith 123456 11/22/3333 1:22:33 PM 654321
```

This is my before.txt file.

```
[CMP DESC]
Text=12345
Text=Text
Text Text=12345
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text=12345
Text Text=12345
Text Text=Text Text
Text Text=d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss AM
Text Text Text=12345
Text Text=d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss AM
Text Text Text=12345
Text Text Text=12345
File Type=4
Text Text Text=Text
Location=3
Text Text=12345
Text=12345
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Text Text=
Job Notes=John Smith 123456 11/22/3333 1:22:33 PM 654321
Text Text=Text
Text=12345.mp3
Text=12345
Text=12345
```

Text file After

```
Name=John Smith
File Number=123456
Date=dd/MM/yyyy
File Type=4
Location=3
```

Comment: You're removing duplicate lines I gather, and then you want to modify the format of each text file.  Can you show an example file, before and after?

Comment: The lines aren't duplicates that are other lines of text that is not needed.  An alternative could be to just modify line 30 (the job notes line) and leave all the other information in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below takes the before file and creates the after file.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
set "input=before.txt"
set "output=after.txt"
findstr /r /i /c:"^Job Notes=" "%input%" |repl ".*=(.*) (\d+) (\d+\/\d+\/\d+) \d+:\d+:\d+ .*" "Name=$1\r\nFile Number=$2\r\nDate=$3" x >"%output%"
findstr /r /i /c:"^File Type=" "%input%" >>"%output%"
findstr /r /i /c:"^Location="  "%input%" >>"%output%"
```

Comment: Nope. All lines start with the text ... no leading spaces.  I have changed now

Comment: Does the `before` file you posted above work for you?

Comment: Got it to work by launching from cmd.  Open cmd with run as administrator.  How do i run the batch normally then with the higher permission?

Comment: Hi foxidrive. Can you update the code in your dropbox? I've added some credits to the documentation, and updated the version to 3.2. The updated version is over on DosTips. Thanks