# Repl.bat to find and replace text from a list of files

Tags: batch-file

This is a follow on from [Batch file to list txt and mp3 files - using the list extract the same lines from the text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753912/batch-file-to-list-txt-and-mp3-files-using-the-list-extract-the-same-lines-fro)
Basically I create a list of text files, then using this list find a line in the text files called "JobNotes=" and output that to a new file with the inforamtion in the Job notes displayed in a different fashion.
I have modified the code to use the findstr on a list of files (file names are in a file text_list).  It creates the first output file fine but then diplays the other output files incorrectly.

This is the code

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (%text_list%) do (
 FINDSTR /l "^Job Notes=" "%%f" |repl.bat ".*=(.*) (\d+) (\d+\/\d+\/\d+) \d+:\d+:\d+ .*" "Name=$1\r\nFile Number=$2\r\nDate=$3" x >"C:\replacer\move\%%f"
                                           )
```

This is the fist output file (which is displayed correctly).

```
Name=John Smith
File Number=123456
Date=22/11/2013
```

Then all other output files diaply like this (which is the way it is diplayed in the input file).

```
Job Notes=Jane Smith 234567 22/11/2013 1:22:33 PM 654321
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an unrelated problem with your FINDSTR - It is not operating as you intended. You are looking for lines that begin with `Job Notes=`, but instead it is looking for any line that contains the string `^Job` or `Notes=`. FINDSTR breaks strings at spaces unless the `/C:"literal search string"` option is used. Your FINDSTR code apparently gives the correct results because only wanted lines contain the string `Notes=`, but you might not want to rely on that.

You can fix it by using a corrected literal search string:

```
FINDSTR /bc:"Job Notes:" ...
```

or a corrected regular expression:

```
FINDSTR /rc:"^Job Notes:" ...
```

Regarding your actual question - REPL.BAT will only modify lines that match the supplied search string; unmatched lines are left as is. You can eliminate unmatched lines by appending the `A` option (altered lines only). But that only hides the problem in your case.

The solution is to modify the regex search string so that it properly matches all input lines.

I suspect that your actual data does not contain `Job Notes=Jane Smith 234567 22/11/2013 1:22:33 PM 654321`, as that line is properly modified by your existing code.

In order for anyone to help you, you must be more precise as to the format of each line (including all variations). Please post some example lines that are not working, along with some that do. Don't change anything, except perhaps modify the letters in the names, and perhaps scramble the numbers - but do not change the count or type of characters in any position.

One other point - the FINDSTR command can probably be dropped with the correct REPL.BAT regex and the addition of the `A` option.

Comment: Found it ..... change in the input file ... one has seconds the other doesn't .... thanks for your help